# Algorithms requiring 4 GB or 5 GB numbers - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, memory, biginteger

Okay, this problem is indeed a challenge!

### Background

I am working on an arithmetic-based project involving larger than normal numbers. I new I was going to be working with a worst-case-senario of 4 GB-caped file sizes (I was hopping to even extend that to a 5GB cap as I have seen file sizes greater than 4 GB before - specifically image *.iso files)

### The Question In General

Now, the algorithm(s) to which I will apply computation to do not matter at the moment, but the loading and handling of such large quantities of data - the numbers - do.

- A `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String)` can only read a cap of 2 GB worth of file data, so this is my first problem - How will I go about loading and/or configuring to access memory, such file sizes - twice as much, if not more?
- Next, I was writing my own class to treat a 'stream' or array of bytes as a big number and add multiple operator methods to perform hex arithmetic until I read about the `System.Numerics.BigInteger()` class online - but being that there is no `BigInteger.MaxValue` and that I can only load a max of 2 GB of data at a time, I don't know what the potential of `BigInteger` would be - even compared to the object I was writing called `Number()` (which does have my desired minimum potential). There were also issues with available memory and performance, though I do not care so much about speed, but rather completing this experimental process successfully.

### Summary

- How should I load 4-5 gigabytes of data?
- How should I store and handle the data after having been loaded? Stick with `BigInteger` or finish my own `Number` class?
- How should I handle such large quantities of memory during runtime without running out of memory? I'll be treating the 4-5 GB of data like any other number instead of an array of bytes - performing such arithmetic as division and multiplication.

PS I cannot reveal too much information about this project under a non-discloser agreement. ;)

For those who would like to see a sample operator from my Number object for a per-byte array adder(C#):

```
public static Number operator +(Number n1, Number n2)
{
    // GB5_ARRAY is a cap constant for 5 GB - 5368709120L
    byte[] data = new byte[GB5_ARRAY];
    byte rem = 0x00, bA, bB, rm, dt;
    // Iterate through all bytes until the second to last
    // The last byte is the remainder if any
    // I tested this algorithm on smaller arrays provided by the `BitConverter` class,
    // then I made a few tweeks to satisfy the larger arrays and the Number object
    for (long iDx = 0; iDx <= GB5_ARRAY-1; iDx++)
    {
        // bData is a byte[] with GB5_ARRAY number of bytes
        // Perform a check - solves for unequal (or jagged) arrays
        if (iDx < GB5_ARRAY - 1) { bA = n1.bData[iDx]; bB = n2.bData[iDx]; } else { bA = 0x00; bB = 0x00; }
        Add(bA, bB, rem, out dt, out rm);
        // set data and prepare for the next interval
        rem = rm; data[iDx] = dt;
    }
    return new Number(data);
}
private static void Add(byte a, byte b, byte r, out byte result, out byte remainder)
{
    int i = a + b + r;
    result = (byte)(i % 256); // find the byte amount through modulus arithmetic
    remainder = (byte)((i - result) / 256); // find remainder
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FileStream`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you would process large files using a streaming API, either raw binary (`Stream`), or via some protocol-reader (`XmlReader`, `StreamReader`, etc). This also could be done via memory-mapped files in some cases. The key point here is that you only look at a small portion of the file at a time (a moderately-sized buffer of data, a logical "line", or "node", etc - depending on the scenario).

Where this gets odd is your desire to map this somehow directly to some form of large number. Frankly, I don't know how we can help with that without more information, but *if* you are dealing with an actual number of this size, I think you're going to struggle unless the binary protocol makes that convenient. And "performing such arithmetic as division and multiplication" is meaningless on raw data; that only makes sense on parsed data with custom operations defined.

Also: note that in .NET 4.5 you can flip a configuration switch to expand the maximum size of arrays, going over the 2GB limit. It still *has* a limit, but: it is a bit bigger. Unfortunately, the maximum number of *elements* is still the same, so if you are using a `byte[]` array it won't help. But if you are using `SomeCompositeStruct[]` you should be able to get higher usage. See [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually I do not see it pointless and my reasoning: I am working on a per-byte bassis. I already successfully wrote a fully functioning Add-Operator on a byte[] and tested it on small numbers first (long l = int.MaxValue + uint.MaxValue; where int.MaxValue = 0x7FFFFFFF, uint.MaxValue = 0xFFFFFFFF, and l would equal 0x017FFFFFFE; I produced the same results on a byte[] - tis just like binary adding in digital electronics)

Comment: @ChristopherWalker in that case, working against a stream or memory-mapped-file should be a breeze. Assuming, of course, that your operation works in a file-forwards direction. If you need file-backwards, you can still *do* it, but it becomes less efficient; for that scenario, I would go with a bigger buffer, to reduce the "seek" impact.

Comment: Perhaps an example of the implementing of big buffers would help me understand? Currently I have now implementing the `FileStream` object in place of the byte[] using unique cache files with a size of the collected non-zero bytes: EX: {0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 00, 12} would be {30, 00, 12} - saves memory and disk space.

Comment: @ChristopherWalker the question is talking abouit 4GB/5GB, not 5 byte. However, if that is a *fragment*, now you need to know: how much padding was subtracted between pieces. Ultimately, it is your data format ... the question you asked was: how to process the raw incoming data....?

Comment: I may have not worded the question right. I'm not sure, but here is a painted pseudo scenario: pretend like I have two files of the same size. Note: I don't treat them like files, but rather like big hex numbers(any endian). The primary operators I supposedly will ever touch: `/`, `%` and `*`; maybe `+` & `-`. The process would be dividing an unknown number(file) 'A' by a new program-defined number(file) 'B'. I would then evaluate the resulting number(file) C for research purposes. And the worst-case-scenario: the unknown file will be between 4GB to 5GBs in size.

Comment: @ChristopherWalker still not sure what the fundamental question is... I understand what you're storing, and I can tell you how to read the data... but: you can't read it into a single huge `byte[]` if it is that big.

Comment: I guess the answer to my questions was the `FileStream` object: Q1. I load or more work with a file on disk instead of an array in memory. Q2. The data is all stored in cache files; I need to finish my number class rapped around the file stream with safe+efficient file caching. Q3. I won't need to worry about memory nearly as much as free hard disk space. **Thanks for your answers and help anyway!**

Answer (score 0):

`FileStream` is the beginning for you.

If you don't have enough memory (it should be at least 4x more than max your number size I think) you will need to use hard disk. So instead having all data in memory you would rather load part of data, do some computing and write it back to hard disk.

Comment: I am already working on a per-byte operation (work with 2 bytes + remainder then output a remainder for the next 2). So, I'm familiar with FileStream, but I don't think I'm so familiar at how it handles the data - I'll re-read up on it on MSDN but just for convenience: File stream only reads a line at a time from a file only storing a portion or eventually storing the entire file in memory?